# form value processing to SQL

Tags: php, sql, image, forms, upload

i used this code to upload multiple image upload now i need to store image path in SQL database for retrieve i just want the path to be stored in database i used multiple image upload and store in folder

```
class Upload_Rename {
const ALLOWED_TYPES = "jpg,gif,png";
public static function generate_new_name($extension, $uppercase = true, $prefix = '', $sufix = '') {
    $new_name = $prefix . uniqid() . '_' . time() . $sufix;
    return ($uppercase ? strtoupper($new_name) : $new_name) . '.' . $extension;
}

public static function check_and_get_extension($file) {
    $file_part = pathinfo($file);
    $allowed_types = explode(",", Upload_Rename::ALLOWED_TYPES);
    if (!in_array($file_part['extension'], $allowed_types)) {
        throw new Exception('Not ok.. bad bad file type.');
    }
    return $file_part['extension'];
}

public function upload($file, $target_destination) {
    if (!isset($file['tmp_name'])) {
        throw new Exception('Whaaaat?');
    }
    $_name = $file['name'];
    $_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $_type = $file['type'];
    $_size = $file['size'];
    $file_extension = '';
    try {
        $file_extension = Upload_Rename::check_and_get_extension($_name);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception('Ops.. file extension? what? ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    $new_name = Upload_Rename::generate_new_name($file_extension, true, 'whaat_', '_okey');
    $destination = $target_destination . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $new_name;
    return move_uploaded_file($_tmp, $destination);
}

public function multiple_files($files, $destination) {
    $number_of_files = isset($files['tmp_name']) ? sizeof($files['tmp_name']) : 0;
    $errors = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files; $i++) {
        if (isset($files['tmp_name'][$i]) && !empty($files['tmp_name'][$i])) {
            try {
                $this->upload(array(
                    'name' => $files['name'][$i],
                    'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$i],
                    'size' => $files['size'][$i],
                    'type' => $files['type'][$i]
                        ), $destination);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                array_push($errors, array('file' => $files['name'][$i], 'error' => $e->getMessage()));
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($errors);
}

}

if ($_FILES) {
$upload = new Upload_Rename();
$destination = 'upload/';
$upload->multiple_files($_FILES['myfile'], $destination);
$path = $upload->multiple_files($_FILES['myfile'], $destination);
}
$mysql_hostname = "";
$mysql_user = "";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "";
$tbl_name="";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not     connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");
// get the value
$name=$path;
// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(path,)VALUES('$name',)";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

?>

<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++): ?>
    file: <input type="file" name="myfile[]"><br>
<?php endfor; ?>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

how do i store file path in SQL and use that path to display in another php page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to insert the paths into your database.

```
<?php
class Upload_Rename {
const ALLOWED_TYPES = "jpg,gif,png";
public static function generate_new_name($extension, $uppercase = true, $prefix = '', $sufix = '') {
    $new_name = $prefix . uniqid() . '_' . time() . $sufix;
    return ($uppercase ? strtoupper($new_name) : $new_name) . '.' . $extension;
}

public static function check_and_get_extension($file) {
    $file_part = pathinfo($file);
    $allowed_types = explode(",", Upload_Rename::ALLOWED_TYPES);
    if (!in_array($file_part['extension'], $allowed_types)) {
        throw new Exception('Not ok.. bad bad file type.');
    }
    return $file_part['extension'];
}

public function upload($file, $target_destination) {
    if (!isset($file['tmp_name'])) {
        throw new Exception('Whaaaat?');
    }
    $_name = $file['name'];
    $_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $_type = $file['type'];
    $_size = $file['size'];
    $file_extension = '';
    try {
        $file_extension = Upload_Rename::check_and_get_extension($_name);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception('Ops.. file extension? what? ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    $new_name = Upload_Rename::generate_new_name($file_extension, true, 'whaat_', '_okey');
    $destination = $target_destination . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $new_name;
    move_uploaded_file($_tmp, $destination);
    return $destination;
}

public function multiple_files($files, $destination) {
    $number_of_files = isset($files['tmp_name']) ? sizeof($files['tmp_name']) : 0;
    $errors = array();
    $paths=array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files; $i++) {
        if (isset($files['tmp_name'][$i]) && !empty($files['tmp_name'][$i])) {
            try {
                $path=$this->upload(array(
                    'name' => $files['name'][$i],
                    'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$i],
                    'size' => $files['size'][$i],
                    'type' => $files['type'][$i]
                        ), $destination);
                 $paths[]=$path;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                array_push($errors, array('file' => $files['name'][$i], 'error' => $e->getMessage()));
            }
        }
    }
    return $paths;
}

}

if ($_FILES) {
$upload = new Upload_Rename();
$destination = 'upload';
$paths=$upload->multiple_files($_FILES['myfile'], $destination);

//Fill this with correct information
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "testdb";
$tbl_name="test";
$pathfield_name='path';
//

$mysql= new mysqli($mysql_hostname,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);

foreach($paths as $path)
{
    $query='INSERT INTO `'.$tbl_name.'` (`'.$pathfield_name.'`) VALUES ("'.$mysql->escape_string($path).'");';
    $mysql->query($query);
}
$mysql->close();
}

?>

<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++): ?>
    file: <input type="file" name="myfile[]"><br>
<?php endfor; ?>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now to retrieve the images make a new file and copy this code there: (this file should be outside the upload folder)

```
<?php

//Fill this with correct information
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "testdb";
$tbl_name="test";
$pathfield_name='path';
//

$mysql= new mysqli($mysql_hostname,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);
$query='SELECT `'.$pathfield_name.'` FROM `'.$tbl_name.'`';
$results=$mysql->query($query);
while($result=$results->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo '<img src="'.$result[$pathfield_name].'">';
}
$results->free();
$mysql->close();
?>
```

SQL query to create the above table (with table name=test and field name=path):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `path` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: whats the SQL comment to create table

Comment: how can i store multiple images in same method

Comment: The code I posted above stores multiple images as well as saves the paths. Just run it.

Comment: at once i upload photo and the path is store but two row is created for single uploading how could i store path of 8 image in single row by using id to retrive

Comment: Sorry I did not get you, please explain in detail.